# EXTJS 5 - ViewModel getting Store returns null value

Tags: extjs, mvvm, viewmodel

Im currently having an issue regarding stores declared in ViewModel, using Extjs5's MVVM feature.

Simple Use case:

ViewModel:

```
Ext.define('App.view.view1.View1Model', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.view1',`
data: {

},
stores:{
       Company:{
                    model: 'UM.model.CompanyData',
                    type: 'CompanyData',             //Store name
                    autoLoad: true      
        }
}
}];
```

While code below is my viewController:

ViewController:

```
Ext.define('App.view.view1.View1Controller', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.view1',
onloadnewdata: function(event, item,store){
            var vm= this.getViewModel();
            var store=vm.getStore('Company');
            console.log(store);
```

}

```
});
```

On firing some event with "onloadnewdata" function based on the console store is null.

All I need to do is get the store declared on the ViewModel. Please help me which part is wrong or is this a bug?
Appreciate if you share some ideas or other approach. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a mock Sencha Fiddle to go with this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to modify the code something like below. In order to get the reference to the ViewModel first you need to get the reference to View.

```
    Ext.define('App.view.view1.View1Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.view1',
    onloadnewdata: function(event, item,store){
        var store = this.getView().getViewModel().getStore('Company');
        console.log(store);
    }
    });
```

You can refer this sencha fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fpb. Just check this following controller TestApp.view.grid.GenericGridController . Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks  for your sample, will try your suggestion.